# IQKeyboardManager not working properly in my view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, iqkeyboardmanager

Currently I have an UI designed that consists of two simple text fields for resetting password. In my viewm, I haven't used the `UIScrollView`. So when the UI displays on an iPhone SE, the UI should move up as the `UITextField` gets hidden behind the keyboard.
To avoid this, I am using a famous library:

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

But still when my UI comes it is not moving up.

[image: UITextField is still hidden under keyboard]

Comment: In my case, it wasn't working because I was using a UIScrollView. When I removed it, it worked just fine. Just commenting to let anybody that's having the same problem that I did know that.

Comment: @Rod Any solution for working with scrollview?

Answer (score 5):

You need to add the following line to the `AppDelegate` (to enable in all the view controllers) or just in the `viewDidLoad` of the `UIViewController` you want to enable the `IQKeyboardManager`.

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following lines to the `AppDelegate`

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().keyboardDistanceFromTextField = 100
```